# XMPP PubSub retrieve node's subscribers

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

I have a PubSub node with two subscribers: Joe and Mike.

I want to retrieve them as a list of subscribers and when I do

```
<iq type='get'
    from='francisco@denmark.lit/barracks'
    to='pubsub.shakespeare.lit'
    id='subscriptions2'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <subscriptions node='my_node'/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

the result is

```
<iq type='result'
    from='pubsub.shakespeare.lit'
    to='joe@denmark.lit'
    id='subscriptions2'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <subscriptions node='my_node'>
      <subscription node='my_node' jid='joe@denmark.lit' subscription='subscribed' subid='123-abc'/>
    </subscriptions>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

It **doesn't show** that Mike is also subscribed to the same node.

And if I make the same query from Mike's account it shows that Mike is the only subscriber and does not include Joe.

Comment: Any updated information if you have got it successfully

Answer (score 1):

Only the node owner can retrieve the list of subscribers.
And the namespace should be "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub**#owner**" for such request.